# Can't add tween to a scene

Tags: phaser-framework

I am quite new to Phaser, but I must be stupidly overlooking something, because I get an error message:

> *'Cannot read property 'add' of undefined'* on the code `gameScene.tweens.add({...})`.

It seems like Phaser doesn't recognize the `tweens` property, but why?
My Phaser version is like `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.js`, not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I now understand... I referenced the variable `gameScene` inside the class named `gameScene`, which produced the error.

Explanation: I tried it because using `this` didn't work. And using `this` didn't work because I had applied it inside the `group.children.iterate` block. Inside this kind of block, `this` seems to be referencing something special.

So, the correct usage appears to be:

```
    var sc=this;
    this.aGroup.children.iterate( function(child) 
    {
        sc.tweens.add({...})
    });
```